# С чем связано определение равенства потоковых итераторов?

Tags: c++, итераторы

Почему 2 `std::istream_iterator` считаются одинаковыми, даже если они указывают на разные элементы одного потока? С чем связано такое определение?

[Two stream iterators are equal if both of them are end-of-stream iterators or both of them refer to the same stream.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator_cmp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `std::istream_iterator` указыает либо на конец связанного потока, либо на EOF. Когда вы выплняете инкремент итератора, он считывает элемент при помощи `operator>>`, а `operator*`, в свою очередь, просто возвращает ранее прочитанный элемент.

Таким образом, `std::istream_iterator` всегда указывает туда, куда "указывает" связанный поток:

```
std::istringstream stream{"1 2 3 4 5"};
std::istream_iterator<int> it1{stream};
std::istream_iterator<int> it2 = it1;


std::cout << *it1 << std::endl; // 1

int i = 0;
stream >> i; // take 2
++it2;       // take 3
++it1;       // take 4

std::cout << *it1 << std::endl; // 4
```

[Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/277c501a7678c1b9)

Answer (score 1):

> если они указывают на разные элементы одного потока?

А такое возможно вообще? Поток как бы синглетон в плане состояния, istream_iterator не скользит по потоку, а просто удобная обертка, чтобы можно было использовать во всех остальных местах STL.

Comment: [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025555/351830) пример. `vnext`-у передаются итераторы, указывающие на разные элементы одного потока

Comment: Ну да, только не работает. Как сказано в мудрой https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator/operator_arith "Reads a value from the underlying stream and stores it into the iterator object". В упомянутом примере `std::next` вызывается на итераторе дважды, в двух аргументах функции, неупорядоченно модифицируя поток. По-моему, это классический пример UB.

Comment: Даже если последовательно сделать 2 `std::next()`, сохранив результаты в 2 итератора `it1` и `it2`, а после передать `it1` и `it2` в `vnext`, то `vnext` будет пустой, потому что `it1 == it2` по определению. Вопрос в том, почему такое определение.

Comment: Ну скажем, если поток одноразовый. Все, что из него прочитано, не может быть расчитано. Любой итератор в этом потоке может указывать только на один-единственный, следующий, элемент. Инкрементируется один — инкрементируются все.
Для более хитрого управления нужны не напрямую стрим-итераторы, а итераторы хитрой обертки, которая кэширует весь поток, запоминает все прочитанные элементы, пока они кому-нибудь нужны.

Answer (score 1):

В потоке нет разных элементов, `istream_iterator` всегда работают с текущим положением потока. Элемент, к которому получается доступ при разыменовании итератора, хранится в самом итераторе, а не где-то в потоке. Этим он радикально отличается от итераторов контейнеров.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что нельзя тогда сохранить текущий `istream_iterator`, а после продвижения использовать это сохранённое значение? Так как этот итератор будет недействительным

Comment: @Матвей Нет, итератор сразу при создании извлечет элемент начиная с текущего положения потока и больше не будет его трогать, пока не произойдет инкремент или присваивание.  Недействительным он станет только после разрушения самого потока или после присваивания концевого итератора. Элемент, к которому получается доступ при разыменовании итератора, хранится в самом итераторе, а не где-то в потоке. Этим он радикально отличается от итераторов контейнеров.